# How to apply equalizer changes to all audio in android?

Tags: android, audio, equalizer

I am using Android `Equalizer` class, and I made some modification to the band levels of the object.

What I need to do is to apply these changes of the equalizer to all the audio files in the device, so when a music file is being played, the changes for the equalizer would be applied to it.

For example, for frequency 1000Hz, I transformed the gain level to 5dB. I need to apply this change to all the audio files.

Thanks

Comment: try it  :- http://androidcluster.blogspot.in/2012/02/mediaplayer-with-visualization-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Hey i am not sure what you trying to do ,but if you want to set the equalizer settings to any audio file which is being played then you can change the session id to 0,so that whatever music/audio is being played,the eq settings will be implemented on them(even the music files that are not being played from your app)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I thought that using 0 for the session id is not applicable.

Comment: does your equalizer use seekbar to change the band- values ?

Comment: The android equalizer has 5 bands. To set the band level you have to use this: `equalizer.setBandLevel((short)0, (short)100);` 0 refers to the first band (frequency 60Hz) and 100 refers to 1 decibel. If you need further information, let me know

Comment: "NOTE: attaching insert effects (equalizer, bass boost, virtualizer) to the global audio output mix by use of session 0 is deprecated." [source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html)